# How can I avoid an extra blank page at the end while printing? tailwindcss

Tags: html, angular, tailwind-css

Working with tailwind CSS and seem to be getting an extra blank page the end for no particular reason.
I have tried using `last:break-after-auto` and `last:hidden` but it seems to have no effect on the print

```
<div class="hidden print:inline">
            <div class="m-0 last:break-after-auto">
                @for (week of store.weeks; track week; let weekIndex = $index)
                {
                    <div class="grid min-h-screen grid-cols-[0.7in_repeat(6,1fr)] grid-rows-[0.4in_0.25in_6.5in]">

                        <div class="col-span-2 col-start-1 mt-5 self-center text-xl font-semibold">Training Schedule {{store.currentSchedule.title}}</div>
                        <div class="col-start-7 self-center text-xl font-semibold">Week {{weekIndex + 1}}</div>

                        @for (day of store.mtcInfoService.info.days; track day)
                        {
                        <div class="col-start-{{day.id}}" [class.hidden]="day.id === 1">{{day.name}}</div>
                        }

                        <div class="col-span-7 grid max-h-[8in] w-full grid-cols-[0.7in_repeat(6,_1fr)] grid-rows-[repeat(68,_1fr)]">

                            @for (hour of store.hours; track hour; let last = $last)
                            {
                            <div class="col-start-1 row-span-4 border-l-[1px] border-t-[1px] border-solid border-black pr-1 text-right" [ngClass]="{'border-b-[1px] border-solid border-black': last}">{{hour.label}}</div>
                            }

                            @for (event of week; track event; let eventIndex = $index)
                            {
                            <div class="border-t-[1px] border-solid border-black pl-[0.75mm] text-sm leading-[10px]" [ngStyle]="getStyle(event,week,eventIndex)">{{event.title}} {{event.startDate | date : 'shortTime':'UTC'}}-{{event.endDate | date : 'shortTime':'UTC'}}</div>
                            }

                            @for (day of store.mtcInfoService.info.days; track day)
                            {
                            <div [class.hidden]="day.id === 1" [class.border-r]="day.id === 7" class="row-span-full w-fit border-[1px] border-r-0 border-solid border-black" [attr.day]="day.name"></div>
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
```

when I tried `last:hidden` it hid the second to last page